# Falla en query MySql PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un error al intentar guardar un objeto dentro de la base de datos, el código es el siguiente.

```
<?php 

include('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['guardar_recordatorio'])){
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

    
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO recordatorios(titulo, descripicion) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion')");

    if (!$resultado){
        die("Falla en la query");
    }

    $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Tarea Guardada";
    $_SESSION['tipo_mensaje'] = 'success';

    header('location: index.php');

}

?>
```

Este es mi formulario.

```
<form action="guardar_recordatorio.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" autofocus name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="guardar_recordatorio" value="Guardar">    
</form>
```

Este es el código dentro del archivo db.php

```
<?php
session_start();


$conn = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',   
    'root',         
    '',             
    'crud_php'      
);



?>
```

Y cuando intento guardar un objeto, me tira el error de "Falla en la query" como si no estuviese guardando un resultado.

No se a que se pueda deber esto.

Comment: qué error te sale?

Comment: Me aparece el die del if(!$resultado)

Comment: Dentro del if(!$resultado) añade print_r(mysqli_error($conn)). A ver si te indica cual es el error que esta teniendo MYSQL con tu consulta.

Comment: podrias incluir el db.php

Comment: Ahí añadí el archivo db.php

Comment: @IbaiA. No me imprime nada, ningun error.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy probable que tengas un error de escritura en esta línea:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO recordatorios(titulo, descripicion) ..."
//  Especificamente AQUI - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ^
```

Supongo que debe ser `descripcion`